# Clarion Database (.dat)

Tags: clarion

I am busy rewriting and redesigning a client's software for them, the software is 20 years old and was written in Clarion, I have the .dat file (2mb in size).

Does anyone know how I can extract the information from the clarion database to a csv, I have googled it however the tools I find only extracts the first 50 rows.

Note that it is not a tps file (for somereason my google searches lead to tps files)

Answer (score 1):

Donald, The TopScan utility that comes with the latest Clarion 10 version opens both Clarion .DAT files and Topspeed .TPS files. You can export to CSV from this tool. If the database is password protected you will need to know the password to open it.

There are also old 16-bit utilities from the DOS version of Clarion called CSCN and CFIL, but I don't know if you can find those.

Comment: Any chance where to download Clarion 10 without buying  it ?

Comment: I am not aware of downloads